# ANOVA with two factor within subjects design

Tags: anova, repeated-measures

So i'm currently frustrating about this method of doing a two-factor repeated measures within subject anova (AxBxS-Design). As there is no straight forward way of using a simple scipy call for my design, i was happy to find some step-by-step instructions in Keppels "Design and Analysis" book. (page 464)

He uses a "simple" method of calculating the sum of squares, but i can't find this method described anywhere else. The big problem that i have right now is, that i receive a negative sum of squares for the ABS Source calculated like this.
[image]

All the data is organized like this:
[image]

I'm confused right now how i should proceed. I can't really find tools online that help me with my design. I'm i correct that SS_ABS = Sum(x-mean(x))? Also what is wrong with the method? I did actually recalculate a lot by hand to see if i did something wrong but can't find any errors.

Comment: I am not familiar with the notation used. From what I can surmise, you have a three-factor ANOVA with 2 levels of factor A, three levels of factor B, and three Students. Thus you have 18 observations altogether, and no replications. This model would not support a three-way interaction. If this is correct, it is no surprise that you would have trouble computing a sum of squares for (impermissible) ABS Interaction. // The rows of the ANOVA table for this design would be A, B, S, AB, AS, BS, and Error/Residual. Some software gives a Total line for columns SS and DF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of an ANOVA according to the model I suggested in my Comment.
Fake data generated to be normal (rounded to integers) with no significant effects are as follows:

```
Data Display 

Row    X  A  B  S
  1  107  1  1  1
  2   86  1  1  2
  3   82  1  1  3
  4  110  1  2  1
  5  120  1  2  2
  6   95  1  2  3
  7  115  1  3  1
  8  105  1  3  2
  9   99  1  3  3
 10  116  2  1  1
 11   92  2  1  2
 12  105  2  1  3
 13  125  2  2  1
 14   95  2  2  2
 15   98  2  2  3
 16  121  2  3  1
 17   93  2  3  2
 18  114  2  3  3
```

The ANOVA table from Minitab software is as follows:

```
ANOVA: X versus A, B, S 

Factor  Type   Levels  Values
A       fixed       2  1, 2
B       fixed       3  1, 2, 3
S       fixed       3  1, 2, 3


Analysis of Variance for X

Source  DF       SS      MS      F      P
A        1    88.89   88.89   1.86  0.244
B        2   362.33  181.17   3.79  0.119
S        2  1156.33  578.17  12.09  0.020
A*B      2   173.44   86.72   1.81  0.275
A*S      2   501.44  250.72   5.24  0.076
B*S      4   218.33   54.58   1.14  0.450
Error    4   191.22   47.81
Total   17  2692.00

S = 6.91416
```

Here are descriptive statistics of the 18 values in `X` (without regard to factors).

Descriptive Statistics: X

```
Variable   N    Mean  StDev  Variance  Minimum     Q1  Median      Q3  Maximum
X         18  104.33  12.58    158.35    82.00  94.50  105.00  115.25   125.00
```

If I try to include the three-way interaction A*B*S in my model, Minitab
gives an error message:

```
* ERROR * Zero or negative degrees of freedom.
```

*Notes:* (a) All of the F-ratios in this particular ANOVA design can be found by dividing
the appropriate MS(Source) by MS(Error). For example, F(A) = 1.86 = 88.89/47.81
and F(BS) = 1.14 = 54.58/47.81. [This is not always so in other ANOVA designs. In some more complex ANOVA designs some of
the F-ratios use denominators other than MS(Error).]

(b) If you take the variance multiplied by 18 - 1 = 17 you get 
SS(Total) = 2692 = 17(158.35). In any ANOVA it is true that the sample variance of the
unstructured data times one less than the grand sample size is SS(Total).

(c) The sample SD of the residuals (here denoted `S`) is the square
root of MS(Error):  $\sqrt{47.81} = 6.913.$ [Both of the identities (b) and (c) 
hold within rounding error, because some of the entries in the ANOVA
table are rounded.]

(d) It happens that the 'Student effect' shows as significant (P-value below 0.05) in the ANOVA
table, even though data were generated not to have any effects. The terminology "5% significance level" indicates that such errors will happen about once in 20 tests, so here you see an example of that. Occasional errors of this type are inevitable.

(e) Some presentations of ANOVA designs in textbooks intended mainly for
psychologists and sociologists are oversimplified and can be easily misinterpreted. Perhaps you have seen an example of that also. Perhaps such misunderstandings could be prevented by more careful exposition.

Comment: Really helpful answer! Would you rather do the MS(A)/MS(Error) instead of the in the book proposed MS(A)/MS(A*S)? Is there any difference for the F-ratios?

Comment: For the model I have used, F(A) = MS(A)/MS(AS) is correct. If you have replications (more than one observation on each student at each combination of levels of factors A and B) and if you then properly consider Students are randomly chosen, the F-ratios can be different. (In part, ratios may depend on whether the 'restricted' or 'unrestricted' version of the model is used. Dealing with that would require more discussion than a Comment.) // I think the tables to which you are referring in your book do not exactly match the data you have (with only one observation per cell).